# jQuery UI sortable - table cells lose border while sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've noticed an interesting effect when sorting table rows in a table with jQuery UI. When sorting starts, the helper appears with no borders! You can drag it all around an see backround through the space where  borders normally should be. The problem only occurs when using IE7 and below.

I've created a jsfiddle, please check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/pTh3R/1/

You could view IE7 behaviour by pressing F12 and then selecting 'Document Mode - Internet Explorer 7 Standards'.

Please, let me know what you know about and a possible solution for that problem. I need to support IE7.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue actually and finally found some time to post here.

You can see the fix here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pTh3R/27/

This fix is ugly and the behaviour is slightly different from standards compliant browsers, but in my certain situation it satisfies my needs. I also use it only to target IE7 and below.